# How to convert a semicolon separated string to classpath

Tags: ant

Is there a possibility to append a dynamically generated string, which contains semicolon separated paths (like “C:\foo;C:\bla;C:\blub;”)  to classpath-container as location?
Or is it possibility to convert a semicolon separated path-string to classpath-container otherwise?

Comment: Not very cross platform way to manage your classpath. One linux it's a colon separated list. Why not use a fileset inside a classpath and build the class path dynamically at runtime?

Comment: Maybe you want the [`pathconvert` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html)?

Comment: From user3240608: Maybe I should concretize my problem further. I have an ant task which compiles an imported complex eclipse project set. It works fine. But now I need unit tests and the Unit test task need some informations e.g. paths of the projects which it depends. So I wrote an ant macro, which delivers all paths I need as string, but I can’t pass this string to the Unit Task, because ant JUnit task expects a classpath structure.